# How to load a different background image for the unselected items of a list

Tags: css, blogger

I am customizing my navigation bar at my blog using simple template.

I have successfuly set a background image for the selected/hover items of a list by declaring this variable:

```
<Variable name="tabs.selected.background.image" description="Selected Tab Background Image" type="url" default="none" value="url(//u/r/l)"/>
```

and added this `background: $(tabs.selected.background.image) repeat-x;` to `.tabs-inner .widget li.selected a,
.tabs-inner .widget li a:hover` section.

Now, I want to add a different background image to the list items that are not selected.
So, I've added a variable named `tabs.background.image` and now I need to add it to the style.
Regarding the tabs, there are these available:

- .tabs-inner
- .tabs-inner .section
- .tabs-inner .widget ul
- .tabs-inner .widget li
- .tabs-inner .widget li a
- .tabs-inner .widget li:first-child a
- .tabs-inner .widget li.selected a, .tabs-inner .widget li a:hover

As I am really new to web development, I tried adding the new variable as a background property to: `tabs-inner .widget li a` but got no background image at the blog.
So, I've tried creating this selection:

```
.tabs-inner .widget li:not(li.selected)
```

This is the final addition:

```
.tabs-inner .widget li:not(li.selected) {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
background: $(tabs.background.image);
}
```

But it doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the background that you want to be used for unselected to all the items. Then use your current code to just change the background of the selected item. Yes?

Comment: I tried adding the background image to the background propery of these selectors: `.tabs-inner .widget li`, `.tabs-inner .widget li a` and nothing happened. :-/ this is what you've meant right?